# C# Action, Closure, and Garbage Collection

Tags: c#, garbage-collection, closures

Do I need to set MyAction to null so that garbage collection will be able to proceed with either of these classes?

I am less concerned when both classes are to have almost the same lifespan.  My question is more appropriate when Class1’s lifespan is much longer then Class2 or when Class2’s lifespan is much longer then Class1.

The code here is stripped down.  Assume that both Class1 and Class2 contain other members and methods that may affect their lifespan.

```
public class Class1 : IDisposable
{
    public Action<string> MyAction { get; set; }

    // Is this necessary?
    public void Dispose()
    {
        MyAction = null;
    }
}

public class Class2
{
    string _result = string.Empty;

    public void DoSomething()
    {
        Class1 myClass1 = new Class1();
        myClass1.MyAction = s => _result = s;
        myClass1.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

> Do I need to set MyAction to null so that garbage collection will be able to proceed with either of these classes?

No. Any time you "Dispose" of a managed resource, odds are good you are doing it wrong. Let the garbage collector do its work.

> I am less concerned when both classes are to have almost the same lifespan. My question is more appropriate when Class1’s lifespan is much longer then Class2 or when Class2’s lifespan is much longer then Class1.

The question doesn't make any sense; *classes* do not have *lifetimes*. **Storage locations have lifetimes.** Precisely which storage locations are you worried about? Can you clarify the question?

I note that there are very serious concerns about extending lifetimes of closed-over variables via closures; your question however is so vague that it is hard to understand whether you are running into such a situation. Let me demonstrate:

```
class Expensive
{
    public byte[] huge = MakeHugeByteArray();
}

class Cheap
{
    public int tiny;
}

class C
{
    public static Func<Cheap> longLived;
    public static void M()
    { 
        Expensive expensiveLocal = new Expensive();
        Cheap cheapLocal = new Cheap();
        Func<Expensive> shortLived = ()=>expensiveLocal ;
        C.longLived = ()=>cheapLocal;
    }
}
```

**What is the lifetime of local variable expensiveLocal?** The lifetime of a local variable is typically *short*; typically local variables live no longer than the method activation. However, **being in a closure extends the lifetime of a local variable arbitrarily long, to the lifetime of the closure.** In this particular case, both lambdas *share* a closure, and that means that the lifetime of local variable expensiveLocal is at least as long as the lifetime of local variable cheapLocal, which has an indefinitely long lifetime because *a reference to the closure has just been stored in a static field that lives forever*. That big byte array might *never* be reclaimed, even though the only thing that seems to reference it has been collected long ago; the closure is a hidden reference.

Many languages have this problem; C#, VB, JScript and so on all have lexical closures that are not partitioned to group variables by lifetime. We are considering changing C# and VB to have better lifetime management for closures but that is far-in-the-future work at this point, so no guarantees.

Comment: It would be extremely useful, if you could elaborate a bit on what it means "share a closure". Visually, it seems like expensiveLocal and cheapLocal variables are totally unrelated. expensiveLocal seems to live only as long as shortLived, which the scope of method M. What are the rules, when such unrelated variables become part of the same closure?

Comment: @Konstantin: Many people seem to believe that the *defining* characteristic of a local variable is that it has a *short lifetime*. Though it is true that many local varibles *do* have short lifetime, and it is true that this is *beneficial*, having a short lifetime is not the *defining* characteristic. What makes a local variable "local" is not its lifetime but rather its *scope*. Remember that scope is defined as *the region of code in which the entity may be referred to by name*. A local is a local because it is only referred to by name *locally* to the body of a method (or lambda).

Comment: @Konstantin: The *lifetime* of a local is *usually* over when control leaves the scope; however, closed-over locals have their lifetimes extended. The specification does not give any rule for how *short* that extension must be, only for how *long* it must be: it must be extended to at least the lifetime of the delegate. **The lifetime is permitted to be extended much longer, and in this unfortunate case, in fact is.** There are no *rules* for when two delegates share a closure; those are implementation details of the compiler and subject to change at any time.

Comment: I understand that currently C# will generate a type for the closure and will make a field to hold expensiveLocal variable and will generate a method on this type. This method will hold the code of shortLived delegate. The instance of this type will created during runtime. But this instance will live as long as expensiveLocal. So there should be no problem, right? Putting a delegate, which references cheapLocal variable into static field is a separate thing, isn't it?

Comment: @Konstantin: The type that has the field that holds the expensive local and the type that has the field that holds the cheap local *are the same type*. That's the problem.

Comment: OK, now I tried to compile your code and I see that C# really generates a single type for both closures and there is just one instance of this type created in "M". Both cheap and expensive locals become fields of this type/instance and the huge array becomes immortal! This is so unexpected. Now I understand your theoretical explanation on compiler guarantees/rules in a totally different way. May I humbly propose this as a theme of a post for your great blog? I think a lot of people would be very surprised :)

Comment: @Konstantin: Great idea. I wrote that article in 2007: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2007/06/06/fyi-c-and-vb-closures-are-per-scope.aspx

Answer (score 4):

No. There's no need to set the reference to null.

`Dispose()` is for cleaning up un-managed resources. `Action<string>` is a manged resource and will be properly handled by the CLR when the instance of `Class1` falls out of scope at the end of `DoSomething()`.

Comment: Question - EventHandlers are managed resources yet if they are not disconnected correctly they seem to keep your objects from being garbage collected...

Comment: @PaulMatovich - Yes, but that is only in certain situations (one class will hold a reference to the method of another which means that things may not fall out of scope as expected). That isn't the case here...you're merely setting an Action<string> to an anonymous function.

Comment: Thanks, that is helpful.  My problem that I see is class1 is holding a reference to code provided by class2 and a class level variable of class2 and therefore not a candidate for garbage collection.  But I am understanding that closure is providing some smoke and mirror action to disconnect that reference.

Answer (score 0):

No, you don't. Garbage collector will handle it.

Answer (score 0):

Once the **DoSomething** returns, **myCLass1** is a candidate for garbage collection. When a class is garbage collected , all its members are collected as well if there are no outstanding references. So you don't need to do what you are doing.